Significance of "shine" vs. "burn" in the song "All of You" from "Encanto"
In "All of You," the final song from the movie Encanto, Mirabel sings:

Look at this family, a glowing constellation
So full of stars, and everybody wants to shine
But the stars don't shine, they burn
And the constellations shift
I think it's time you learn
You're more than just your gift

The first two lines are a callback to the first song, "The Family Madrigal," in which Mirabel sings:

This is my family, a perfect constellation
So many stars, and everybody gets to shine

But Mirabel, despite being part of the family, does not feel that she gets to shine: unlike the others, she has no supernatural gift. As she sings in "Waiting on a Miracle":

Hey, I'm still a part of the Family Madrigal
And I'm fine, I am totally fine
I will stand on the side as you shine...
I'm not fine, I'm not fine

"All of You" reflects the family's character development over the course of the movie: they are learning that "perfect" is not the goal and that their family bonds are more important than their supernatural abilities. To that end, Mirabel takes the metaphor of stars and reframes it: "the stars don't shine, they burn." Presumably, "shine" represents being gifted, since Mirabel felt that she couldn't. But what does "burn" represent? How does this change of wording (between two near-synonyms, in the context of stars) symbolize the change of mindset Mirabel and her family need to undergo?

The shine vs. burn distinction is about the surface level vs. inner self. Shining is entirely external. Something shining bright on the surface looks cool from far off, but that doesn't tell you anything about what's happening inside. Burning is internal. Something from within is being used and then shown off. The interior-ness of burning is evident in the metaphors we associate with burning, such as "a burning passion" - the passion comes from within.
Struggles with how one presents themselves externally compared to their personal feelings are everywhere in the musical. As you note, the family learns over the musical to stop striving for perfection but instead focus on family bonds and inherent worth. The shining isn't just based on the supernatural gifts but the entire external presentation: Luisa pretending to be strong but not anxious, Isabela pretending to be perfect but not wanting her betrothed, etc.
Mirabel never had a gift, but in "All of You" everyone else acknowledges, "We see how bright you burn / We see how brave you've been" because it was her inner drive to save her family with her meager non-supernatural abilities that, ultimately, saved the day. Her "brave"-ness, an inner trait, is tied to her "burn"-ing.
The Madrigal family has to change their mindset from judging based on how someone shines on the outside, to how someone burns on the inside. That external presentation could always change - "constellations shift" - but the inner burning is inherent to the person themself.

When something shines, it glows (or reflects), and the implication is that it just happens, as a fundamental property. Something could "shine" forever.
But stars don't really shine, they burn -- via fusion, their fuel is consumed to create their light, and they may appear timeless but they can't keep it up forever and will eventually "burn out". The constellations shift also, as stars are constantly moving.
Both the burning and moving happen so slowly that most of the time we can't perceive it, so we think of stars as both immortal and fixed in the sky. They seem unable to fail or falter, and they create an impression of effortless perfection.
The song seems to indicate that this is the wrong perception, and in fact in order to achieve lasting enjoyment of life, one needs to avoid relying on gifts or talents that can weaken or disappear, or become irrelevant as life changes. Mirabel has had to build her life and her self without having gifts to rely on. So, she is actually further ahead on the path that her family members will need to follow.
